# Filter child class date field in DRF

Tags: django, django-models, filter, django-rest-framework

I'm new in DRF , i need to child class filed filter in parent view

**models.py**

```
class Customer(Base):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class Cart(Base):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="cart")
    cart_number = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=increment_cart_number, null=True, blank=True)
    total_summa = models.FloatField(default=0)
  
    is_saved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Base(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

**filters.py**

```
class CustomerListFilter(rest_framework.FilterSet):
    name = rest_framework.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = [
            'name',
            'phone_number',
        ]
```

I need to filter the list of customer's carts according to the dates of the carts

Answer (score 0):

```
created_at = = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name="created_at", label="Created at")
```

you can also lookup_expr "lte","gte" to filter.

```
created_from = = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name="created_at",
lookup_expr="gte", label="Created From")

created_to = = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name="created_at",
lookup_expr="lte", label="Created To")
```

don't forget to add filters to fields.

```
class CartListFilter(rest_framework.FilterSet):
      created_at = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name="created_at", label="Created at")
      class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = [
            'created_at',
        ]
```

Comment: But it filter by Customer created_at fileld , i need Cart created_at filed filter in this filterset class

Comment: create another custom filter class with a class meta model with Cart. @XursandbekIbadullayev

Comment: please write me code

Comment: @XursandbekIbadullayev I have updated my answer. please check it

Comment: `FilterSet model <class 'customers.models.Cart'> does not match queryset model <class 'customers.models.Customer'>` this error